# How to set style of a single edge in the tree (TikZ) ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

The Tikz manual gives "edge from parent" construct.
But it is [peculiar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/is-this-a-tikz-bug/) (it changes all the edges in subtree and some nodes).
How to color and thicken exactly one edge?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Mikael mentioned in his answer to your previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/is-this-a-tikz-bug/), I don't think this is actually a bug, but simply how TikZ works.  So the solution to the problem is to change a specific branch, and then change it back on its daughters.  As you ask in your comment, you can define two styles for plain and emphasized edges respectively, to save you some typing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    level 1/.style={sibling distance = 2cm, level distance = 1cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance = 1cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance = 1cm},
    every node/.style={circle, draw=black,thin, minimum size = 0.5cm},
    emph/.style={edge from parent/.style={red,very thick,draw}},
    norm/.style={edge from parent/.style={black,thin,draw}}
  ]

  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \node{} 
    child[emph] { node {}
      child[norm] { node {} }
      child[norm] { node {}
        child[emph] { node {} }
        child { node {} }
      }
    }
    child { node {}
      child { node {} }
      child { node {} }
    }
    child { node {} }
    ;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I save a whole style to a variable and use it like that: child[SAVED_STYLE] ?

Comment: Yes.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Can I replace: "emph/.style={edge from parent/.style={red,very thick,draw}}" with "emph/.style={red,very thick,draw}" ?

Comment: @Lukasz Why not try it and experiment?  (You can't, though.)

Comment: I did, it worked, that's why I asked :)

Comment: @Lukasz Actually I don't think it does in all cases, so be careul. (e.g. if you remove the `edge from parent/style)` from the example above, the lower emphasised branch is no longer emphasised.

Comment: if i want to change the edges in the whole tree, how can i do that in one shot?, not to put `emph` for every node. How can i make this option general?.

Comment: @Misaki You don't need the `emph` and `norm` styles, just use `edge from parent/.style={red, very thick,draw}`.