# Dashed edges from parent to normal edge in child in trees

Tags: tikz-trees

I am creating a tree in which the edges from a child to its children are dashed. I got this using `child[dashed]`. Now all the edges of these children are dashed.

I want to override this. So unable to find this command, I tried `child[normal]` and `child[solid]` in its children; both did not work. Also `child[thick]` and `child[thin]` does not changed the dashed nature.

Please can anyone tell me the correct command to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From manual for Tikz (pp 323):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick}]
\node {root}
child {node {left} edge from parent[dashed]}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child} edge from parent[draw=none]}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

follows, that you can define style of each edge in tree. To be more specific, you should provide a MWE, which show your problem.

Comment: `set edge from parent[dashed]` will make _all_ edges below this child dashed. The example from the manual applies to a child without further children. I want to switch off dashed for all children; so, only one dashed edge (and it's not to a leave).

Comment: My comment was really more meant to draw attention to a limitation in the example from the manual. My "question" is already answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9241/how-to-set-style-of-a-single-edge-in-the-tree-tikz).

Comment: You quoted the example from the manual. Unfortunately, that example is too limited to help the OP.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `forest` you can specify this once for the relevant parent and still limit the effect to its immediate children. In addition, specifying a tree involves less typing ;).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
  },
  [root, for children={edge=dashed}
    [child 1
      [grandchild 1]
      [grandchild 2]
    ]
    [child 2
      [grandchild 3]
      [grandchild 4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: dashed children and unblemished grandchildren]