# Draw Morse tree with tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

I like to replicate this Morse tree from Wikipedia [image: morse tree] with tikz

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle}, thick]
\node{Start}
    child { 
        node {E} 
        edge from parent [dotted]
        child { 
           node {I}
           edge from parent [dotted]
           child { 
             node {S}
             edge from parent [dotted]
             }
           child { 
             node {U}
             edge from parent [dashed]
           }
        }
        child { 
           node {A}
           edge from parent [dashed]
           child { 
             node {R}
             edge from parent [dotted]
             }
           child { 
             node {W}
             edge from parent [dashed]
           }
           }
    }
    child { 
        node {T}
        edge from parent [dashed]    
    };
 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

problems

- how to prevent R and U cover each other
- how to prevent the circles themselves being dashed / dotted

Comment: [The answer to your questions.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350274/132778)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With package `forest`, which is based on `tikz`, is simpler than with pure `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
%   nodes style
    circle, draw, minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=1pt, font=\small,
%   tree styles
    anchor=north,
    l sep=11mm,
    s sep=1mm,
%
    if n=1{edge={semithick, dotted}} % odd/left edges
          {edge={semithick,dashed}}  % even/right edges
            }
[start, name=s
    [e, name=s
        [I
            [S
                [H
                    [5, tier=L6]
                    [4]
                ]
                [V
                    []
                    [3]
                ]
            ]
            [U
                [F
                    []
                    []
                ]
                [
                    []
                    [2]
                ]
            ]% end of U
        ]% end of I
        [,phantom, tier=L6]
        [A
            [R
                [L
                    []
                    []
                ]
                [L
                    [+]
                    []
                ]
            ]
            [W
                [P
                    []
                    []
                ]
               [J
                    []
                    [1]
                ]
            ]% end of W
        ]% end of A
    ]% end of E
    [,phantom, tier=L6]
%%%%
    [T, name=t
        [N
            [D
                [B
                    [6]
                    [=]
                ]
                [X
                    [/]
                    []
                ]
            ]% end of D
            [K
                [C
                    []
                    []
                ]
                [Y
                    []
                    []
                ]
            ]%end of K
        ]% end of N
        [,phantom, tier=L6]
        [M
            [G
                [Z
                    [7]
                    []
                ]
               [Q
                    []
                    []
                ]
            ]% end of G
            [O
                [ 
                    [8]
                    []
                ]
               [
                    [9]
                    [0]
                ]
            ]% end of O
        ]% end of M
    ]% end of T
]
\draw[-stealth, dotted] (s-|e) -- node[above] {Dot}  ++ (-4em,0);
\draw[-stealth, dashed] (s-|t) -- node[above] {Dash} ++ (+4em,0);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Tree is quit wide, so my consider to rotate tree for 90 degree. For this you only need to define direction of tree growth and accordingly determined arrows direction:

```
%   tree styles
    anchor=west, grow=0,
```

and

```
\draw[-stealth, dotted] (s |- e) -- node[above, rotate=90] {Dot}  ++ (0,-4em);
\draw[-stealth, dashed] (s |- t) -- node[above, sloped] {Dash} ++ (0,+4em);
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: I think the second L is not quite right...

Comment: @Thruston, you are right. I should be dropped. I correct this now and add missed arrows ...