# Changing the style of all edges in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

How can I change the style of **all** the edges in code below like the red one? I tried adding `every edge/.style={..}` but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}        

\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={font=\huge},
level distance=1.1cm,sibling distance=.8cm, 
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}],
frontier/.style={distance from root=350pt} % Align leaf nodes

\Tree 
[
\edge [ultra thick, dashed,red] node[black,near end,left] {branch};
[   
\edge node[near end, left] {};
[
\edge node[] {}; [.a ]
\edge node[] {}; [.b ]        
]        
\edge node[] {}; [.c ]
]
\edge node[near end,right] {};
[   
\edge node[] {}; [.d ]
\edge node[] {}; [.e ]
]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}        

\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={font=\huge},edge from parent/.style={draw,red,ultra thick,dashed},
level distance=1.1cm,sibling distance=.8cm, 
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}],
frontier/.style={distance from root=350pt} % Align leaf nodes

\Tree 
[
\edge  node[black,near end,left] {branch};
[   
\edge node[near end, left] {};
[
\edge node[] {}; [.a ]
\edge node[] {}; [.b ]        
]        
\edge node[] {}; [.c ]
]
\edge node[near end,right] {};
[   
\edge node[] {}; [.d ]
\edge node[] {}; [.e ]
]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I found it here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9242/120578

I just change it for every edge. But it is almost a duplicate... Let others decide (I will not mark it because it is different question even if the answer is there)

Comment: Order matters! i.e. if we use `edge from parent/.style={draw,red,ultra thick,dashed}, `  **after** `edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}],`, then the style won't apply (idk why)